# Method for solving a system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm stuck on problem 3.4.1 of Berkeley Problems in Mathematics. It states the following:

> Consider the system of differential equations:
>
> $\frac{dx}{dt} = y + tz$
>
> $\frac{dy}{dt} = z + t^2x$
>
> $\frac{dz}{dt} = x + e^ty$
>
> Prove that there exists a solution defined for all $t \in [0, 1]$, such that $$
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 2 & 3 \\
> 4 & 5 & 6 \\
> 7 & 8 & 9
> \end{pmatrix}
> \quad 
> \begin{pmatrix}
> x(0) \\
> y(0) \\
> z(0)
> \end{pmatrix}
> \quad =
> \begin{pmatrix} 
> 0 \\
> 0 \\
> 0
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>
> and also $\int_{0}^{1} (x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 + z(t)^2) dy = 1$.

Now I understand that the matrix implies that $x, y, z$ are $0$ at $t = 0$, and that if we could prove that $x, y, z$ are continuously differentiable then we would be done by the existence/uniqueness  theorem.

I don't know how to proceed from here though, is the integral simply a hint for finding functions $x, y, z$ or is there some method I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear system is not regular, its solution set is determined as $z(0)=x(0)$, $y(0)=-2x(0)$.

As the ODE system is linear, you only need the solution for $x(0)=1$, all others are multiples of it, and you can determine a scaling factor so that also the integral condition is satisfied.